# Tags, classes and attributes in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I finished learning `Bootstrap-3` and I'm still confused about the `tags` & the `classes` and `attributes`.

1. Should classes like `navbar` or `form-group` work the same using the exact name tag `<nav>` or `<form>` used in the documentation? Because I saw many tutorials using the tag `<div>` instead? I mean is `<div>` working with all classes? And which classes works with a specific tags ?
2. I would like you to recommend me with a good editor defined with `bootstrap` except `Sublime`.
3. Is there a PDF reference for bootstrap tags, classes and attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Joe and welcome to the forum, first of all you should try to use punctuation when asking a question to make it easier for users to respond.

To answer your questions:

1. No there aren't specific rules or restrictions concerning the application of classes to specific tags. However, some properties might not be applicable to all kind of tags or be meaningless.
2. I am using Atom - https://atom.io/
3. Not one that I am aware of, but the online documentation does a pretty good job; I can only assume you want to read it offline, so you should try saving the online documentation pages locally.

As an added bonus, if you start understanding `Bootstrap 3`, why not move to learning `Bootstrap 4`? Although from your questions you seem new to the development "sport", so you should try reading other sources first, (like W3Schools - https://www.w3schools.com/) to have a better understanding of how things work.